# Is there module that will add a drop down widget that auto-populates with a list of the site users?

Tags: 7, entities

Looking to have a "field widget" that creates a drop down populated with the site's users.  I'm not sure "field widget" is the right term.  I just mean a widget that's used in a field.

Does anyone know of such a module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references)  module

> This project provides D7 versions of the 'node_reference' and 'user_reference' field types, that were part of the CCK package in D6, at functional parity with the D6 counterparts. See http://drupal.org/node/533222 for details.

Similar module is [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference)

> Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities:

You can add a new field for user list by selecting ***User Reference*** as a field type and ***select list*** as Widget Type in your content type.

Here is the screenshot for that

[image]